# Evaluation of passed parameters inside macro body

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I have a doubt on how parameters passed to the macros are getting evaluated, details below.

This macro is defined

```
(defmacro test-macro (xlist)
    `(* ,@xlist))
```

and there is this global variable `(defvar *test-list* '(1 100 2 200))`.

When `*test-list*` is passed to this macro `(test-macro *test-list*)` , this error is returned -

```
value *TEST-LIST* is not of the expected type LIST.
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

But if the function is modified to this, list is returned

```
(defmacro test-macro (xlist)
    `(,@xlist)) ;; removed the * operator
```

`(test-macro *test-list*)` will return `(1 100 2 200)`.

So my doubt is why `,@xlist` is not getting evaluated in the first case, i.e when the `*` operator is applied. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

When debugging macros, The Right Way is to use [`macroexpand`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm), not evaluate the macro forms. E.g., in your case:

```
(defmacro test-macro1 (xlist) `(* ,@xlist))
(macroexpand '(test-macro1 foo))
==> (* . FOO)
(defmacro test-macro2 (xlist) `(,@xlist))
(macroexpand '(test-macro2 foo))
==> FOO
```

neither is probably what you want.

Comment: @5fists There's a hotkey for macroexpand in slime; it's ,1 for slimv

Answer (score 3):

The confusion is that the macro is a **pre-processor**: it has no built-in mechanism to know of runtime values.  So when you use the term:

```
(test-macro test-list)
```

all that the macro sees is the identifier `test-list`: it does not know up-front that the runtime value is a list, only that the source program has used this variable identifier.

A macro is a source-to-source rewriter: it doesn't know about the dynamics of your program.  A smarter compiler might be able to see that test-list is a constant and do an inlining, but the macro expander isn't that clever.

What you can do is probably something like this:

```
(defmacro test-macro (xlist)
  (cond
    (;; If we see test-macro is being used with a quoted list of things
     ;; then we can rewrite that statically.
     (and (pair? xlist)
          (eq? (car xlist) 'quote)
          (list? (cadr xlist)))
     `(list 'case-1 (* ,@(cadr xlist))))

    (;; Also, if we see test-macro is being used with "(list ...)"
     ;; then we can rewrite that statically.
     (and (pair? xlist)
          (eq? (car xlist) 'list))
     `(list 'case-2 (* ,@(cdr xlist))))

    (else
     ;; Otherwise, do the most generic thing:
     `(list 'case-3 (apply * ,xlist)))))



;; This hits the first case:
(test-macro '(3 4 5))

;; ... the second case:
(test-macro (list 5 6 7))

;; ... and the third case:
(defvar test-list '(1 100 2 200))
(test-macro test-list)
```

---

With regards to your second version: the macro:

```
(defmacro test-macro (xlist)
  `(,@xlist))
```

is equivalent to:

```
(defmacro test-macro (xlist)
  xlist)
```

so that's why you're not getting the error that you received in the first version.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in such a detail. Some of the functions you have used in your code is not available in the Common Lisp implementation which I am using.Can't say I understand your code entirely, but got few important points which will be very helpful in my further learning of Lisp. Seems like I have a long way to go :).